# Troubleshooting a blank window

Tags: microsoft-windows, start-up

I've run into a bit of an issue that I'm having trouble resolving.  I use quite a few packages, one of which is ESS.  The latest update to ESS seems to run into issues when trying to install.  All I get is a blank window  when I try to start it.  I can start Emacs with `-Q`, but `--debug-init` doesn't help at all.  I've tried using melpa-stable instead, but I rely on too many packages from melpa to make that jump.  I've also tried deleting all elpa packages and letting them reinstall, but it gets stuck at installing ESS.  I can't interact with the window at all, and it's stayed blank like that for at least 30 minutes.

- Windows 10
- Emacs 25.0.50 (Emacs w64)

[image: blank Emacs window]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. How do you compile ESS? Why? What does `-Q works` mean? You can compile ESS when you use `emacs -Q`?

Comment: @Tyler Sorry for the confusion. Hopefully the edits clarified things.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the ESS package. I just updated it on my Linux laptop with no problems, so maybe something Windows-specific. I believe you can add both melpa and melpa-stable, and then select which repository to use for each package. It might be worth trying to see if the melpa-stable ESS works properly.